# TypeScript - How can I access "this" in async method

Tags: typescript, async-await, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of code:

```
export class Profile {

    private resource: Resource = new Resource();


    /**
     * Problem here
     */
    async initialize(): Promise<void> {
        console.log(this.resource);

        var html = await this.resource.fetch(true);

        const $profile = jQuery(html);

        console.log($profile.find("span.largetext"));


    }
}
```

If you can see the line `console.log(this.resource)`, I get undefined. Can't async methods access the "this"?

I also tested with `console.log(this)`, and it returns `Profile { }` in the web inspector.

Is there a way I can access `this`?

Comment: What `this` refers to depends on how the method is called.

Comment: @FelixKling What would it change exactly?

Comment: Well, the value of `this`. But I just realized that you said it would refer to a `Profile` instance. In that case `this` doesn't have a `resource` property for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Profile {

    private resource: number = 1;


    /**
     * Problem here
     */
    async initialize(): Promise<void> {
        console.log(this.resource);
    }
}


let p = new Profile();
p.initialize();


let p = new Profile();
p.initialize();
```

I created this sample script which transpiles to

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, Promise, generator) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        generator = generator.call(thisArg, _arguments);
        function cast(value) { return value instanceof Promise && value.constructor === Promise ? value : new Promise(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
        function onfulfill(value) { try { step("next", value); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function onreject(value) { try { step("throw", value); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(verb, value) {
            var result = generator[verb](value);
            result.done ? resolve(result.value) : cast(result.value).then(onfulfill, onreject);
        }
        step("next", void 0);
    });
};
class Profile {
    constructor() {
        this.resource = 1;
    }
    /**
     * Problem here
     */
    initialize() {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, Promise, function* () {
            console.log(this.resource);
        });
    }
}
let p = new Profile();
p.initialize();
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

and the output is

```
1
```

as expected. So the conclusion is that it's not about `this` keyword. It's about `Resource` class, I guess.

Comment: hi @MartyIX, in es2017 inside the async method for me I am able to access console.log(this) and it is also displaying in the console but during debugging when I am manually typing 'this' in the console then it is showing as undefined

Any suggestion or solution for this issue